# There is a cycle in G that contains all vertices of $P$ except (at most) one

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

> Let G be an $n$-by-$n$ bipartite graph with minimum degree $\delta> n/2$, and let $P$ be a *maximal* path in it. Prove that there is a cycle in G that contains all vertices of $P$ except (at most) one.

Actually it should be true without that maximality restriction, i.e. for an arbitrary path

How to approach this problem, with induction, contradiction ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $P=v_1v_2\ldots v_m$.

If $v_1$ and $v_m$ are of the same colour, they have a common neighbour $w$ (because together they have $\ge 2\delta>n$ neighbours). Then $v_1v_2\ldots v_mwv_1$ is our desired cycle.

If $v_1$ and $v_m$ are of different colour, use $v_1$ and $v_{m-1}$ instead.

Comment: So you're only distinguishing whether $v_1$ and $v_m$ are on the same partite set or not, and using 2 colorability of bipartite graphs right ? Thanks

Comment: Isn't it possible that $w$ is identical to some $v_i$? In fact, if $P$ is a maximal path, then $w$ MUST be identical to some $v_i$ (otherwise we could extend the path)

Answer (score 1):

Although I do not think this is what you intended with this problem, technically this provides a solution to the problem as stated.

We have that $\delta(G) > \frac{n}{2}$, and so by a theorem of Moon and Moser ('63), we have that $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle $C$. Since $C$ is a cycle that contains all the vertices of any path $P$, we are done.

Comment: I thought the same but here we have $n$ by $n$ bipartite graph, so totally $2n$ Vertices.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of Dirac's theorem about Hamiltonian Cycles. There is actually a similar theorem by Moon and Moser about balanced bipartite graphs that gives this desired result: for any bipartite graph $G$ with $n$ vertices in both parts, if $\delta(G) > \frac{n}{2}$, then $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle. There may be a quicker way to solve your problem, however,

Comment: Yes, that what I meant was of Dirac.  We didnt treat the Theorem you mentioned. And this is a past exam question, I think one to Show a bit of his own work, rather than just writing a Theorem. Thanks for your answer though